# Where to define a function for use within a Yii's view?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm developing a web application with Yii2.

I am passing an array from my controller to my view for display as a table. Each element in the array is a sub-array that represents a table row. However, the sub-array, where each element represents a table cell, can be made up of both strings and "sub-sub-arrays". In the case of a string, then the string would just be output in a table cell. In the case of a sub-sub-array, I want to "unwind" the array for display. Again, these sub-sub-arrays can be made of strings or "sub-sub-sub-arrays". And so on.

What is the best way of approaching this? I'm thinking that I should write a recursive function to unwind the array in the view. If it's a string, then output, else if it's an array, unwind the array.

Writing the function itself seems straightforward to me, but where do I actually define it? Does it go in my controller class? Somewhere else? I'm thinking that I will call it from my view. Within the Yii structure, how do I call it such that it is within scope (if I'm using the right term) and being called correctly?

So in my controller, I would have something like:

```
return $this->render('//messages', [
    'table' => $array_to_unwind
]);
```

And in my messages.php view file, I would have something like the following, where the unwind() function outputs a string if it's a string, or unwinds an array if it's an array:

```
<table>
  <?php
  foreach ($table as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $cell) {
      echo '<td>';
      unwind($cell);
      echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create own `Helper` (for example in `path-to-project/components/` - in Basic Template) class to do such things, and inside create static functions.

```
<?php

namespace app\components;

class MyHelper
{
     public static function unwind($param) {
            // here body of your function
     }
}
```

Then in view call it:

```
foreach ($row as $cell) {
  echo '<td>';
  echo \app\components\MyHelper::unwind($cell);  //or without echo if your function is doing it, but it will be better if function will return value instead of echoing it
  echo '</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this through using Yii components. 
components are usually placed in `path/to/your/project/components` directory. define your own component and place a **static** function in your component class.

Example:

```
namespace app\components;

Class MyComponent extends Component {
    public static function unwind(){
       // your code here..

      return $array;
    }

}
```

Then in your view:

```
use app\components\Mycomponent;

....
....
echo MyComponent::unwind();
```

Comment: note you haven't actually included the `static` keyword in your function definition

Answer (score -1):

```
if i have get your question right, and if you are looking for recursive function than this can be helpful.  

    // add foreach in html
    foreach ($table as $row) {
        if (is_array($row)) {
          unwind($row);
        }else{
            <html you want to print if its string>
        }
    }

    //create a function in same view file

    function unwind($data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value){
          <html you want to print if its an array>
        }   
    }
```

Comment: I don't need help with the recursive function. I wanted to know more about the app structure and where to put my custom helper function and how to access it.

Comment: you can create your custom helper in component folder in /protected/components/CustomHelper.php 
...

class CustomHelper extends CApplicationComponent
{
    public static function YourFunction($data){
     .................
     you code
    .................
}


and you can access it in view like this 

CustomHelper::YourFunction($data);